# How can handle session state in angularJS with json api auth

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, cordova, api

I want to create a new post from mobile app using wp-rest api, in order to do this I have to logged in with a form; well, the authentication with json api auth works well I submit username and password and I enter; but, when I try to create a new post with wp-rest api I have this error :"You don't have permission to do this." It seems that I'm not logged in but I'm !!!

my code is this :

```
       var data={"title":"Hello World!","content_raw":"Content","excerpt_raw":"Excerpt"};

    $scope.register = function() {

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://url.com/provawp/wp-json/wp/v2/posts',
            data: data,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) { 
            alert("Città aggiunta correttamente!"); 
        }) 
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        }).
        catch(function (error) {
         alert("Erroreee!");
        console.log("error : " + JSON.stringify(error) );

       }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using web tokens. You can put your token inside your http header by creating  http interceptors

Comment: can you explain me how ? I have cookie var

Comment: If you use cookie your post requests should be fine, can you make sure your back-end server receives the cookie from the incoming request?

Answer (score 0):

and also you use like this:

```
$http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://url.com/provawp/wp-json/wp/v2/posts',
        data: data,
        headers: {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization' : 'bearer Dfdsf54sdff#dfsdsfFF'
               }
    })
```

you contact you back end developer for this situation:

**bearer** and any other

**Dfdsf54sdff#dfsdsfFF** your Authorization token

Comment: I have cookie var; it's the same? backend is wordpress

Comment: you not use rest api?

Comment: For authentication I use json api auth do you know?

Comment: so if you login then server response with a token, token type, refresh token, etc...

Comment: server response is a cookie;